# Which combination of tools would you use for a hybrid Mobile Task and Time Management app?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, web-development, mobile, react

I want to create a Time and Task Management app where 20 co-workers would get tasks administered by 2 admins. This should be a hybrid app because it should work both on iOS and Android devices.

I personally was thinking about React JS as + Firebase as a solution, however I'm not sure if that would be the best direction to go in. I'd like to get an advice from experienced Web-App Developer, which combination of tools would you use? You can also see some attached MockUp Pictures.

Thank you and with best regards
Daniels

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not ReactJs, but React NAtive